# Only a portion of code block displaying

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm trying to post some code in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8074/why-is-the-earth-so-fat/8114#8114), but only a portion of the code I've copied is showing up.  What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think I see what's going on: IIRC HTML is still interpreted inside a `<pre>` block, so the parser saw a less-than sign in your code and treated it as the start of an HTML tag. Another user edited the post to use indentation instead of a `<pre>` block, so now it displays correctly since HTML is not parsed within an indented Markdown code block.